# Spring MVC application and static content updating

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, resources

Here's the deal.
I've got a small Spring MVC web-application using static content in its work. Static content like .css or .jpg files is located in /RESOURCES directory and is available without any problems by way of using `mvc:resources` tag but I can't get an access to files, which were uploaded in the course of application working into /RESOURCES folder, without restarting the server. However I need them in my application. 
If anyone would help me with that please?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static resources were created to optimize the time these resources are served. And the optimization is made at build time, so it can't no reload automatically by definition.

https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/24/spring-framework-4-1-handling-static-web-resources

Comment: I followed the link you suggested, asked there my question and got some response, which eventually wouldn't solve my problem. But it may be useful in other cases so I recommend to read comments over the blog